# Having trouble figuring out the loop

Tags: c++, loops

The program reads text from an input file.
My output is suppose to read:

```
Level         Score          Stars
----------------------------------
1              3840           **
2              5940           **
3             11560           **
4             18140           **
5             18780           **
```

It displays the level and scores but the problem is the display of the stars. The rest of the program displays stars instead of the output.

I cant seem to figure out why the stars keep looping but not the output?

```
#include <iostream> // access to cin, cout
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>  
#include<cmath> 
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int buildArrays(int A[],int B[],int C[]) {

    int a, i = 0;                //  (I think this is where the looping problem begins)
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open( "candycrush.txt" );

    if ( inFile.fail() ) {
        cout << "The candycrush.txt input file did not open";
        exit(-1);
    }

    inFile >> a;
    while(inFile) {                                  
        A[i] = a;
        inFile >> a;
        B[i] = a;
        inFile >> a;
        C[i] = a;
        inFile >> a;
        i++;
    }
    inFile.close();
    return i;
}

void printArrays( string reportTitle, int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels ) {
    cout << reportTitle << endl;
    cout << "Levels\tScores\tStars" << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLevels; i++) {
        cout << levelsArray[i] << "\t" << scoresArray[i] << "\t";
        for(int j = 0; j < starsArray[i]; j++) {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void sortArrays( int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels ) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfLevels; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfLevels; j++) {
            if(levelsArray[i] < levelsArray[j]) {
                int temp1 = levelsArray[i];
                int temp2 = scoresArray[i];
                int temp3 = starsArray[i];

                levelsArray[i] = levelsArray[j];
                scoresArray[i] = scoresArray[j];
                starsArray[i]  = starsArray[j];
                levelsArray[j] = temp1;
                scoresArray[j] = temp2;
                starsArray[j]  = temp3;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    const int MAX=400;
    int levelsArray[MAX];
    int scoresArray[MAX];
    int starsArray[MAX];

    int numberOfLevels = buildArrays(levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray);

    printArrays( "Candy Crush UNSORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );
    sortArrays( levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels);
    printArrays( "Candy Crush SORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Maybe `for(int j=0;j<starsArray[i];j++)` is `starsArray[j]` here

Comment: I just did some code reformatting for you. Usually, I would expect you to state your questions with code formatted similar to this (indent, use spaces!). A lot of people around here are willing to help, but you should help them to spot your problem as quick as possible. On way to do this is to format your code in a standard way.

Comment: So your saying state the questions with the same indent as the coding?

Comment: I always thought people would want to see the different layout to spot the questions easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<numberOfLevels;j++){
            if(levelsArray[i]<levelsArray[j]){
```

1. You're comparing the same array
2. i's and j's initial value is both 0

As a result, the program will never go inside the scope of the if-statement.

I think you meant:

```
for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++){
    if(levelsArray[i]<levelsArray[i+1]){
```

Comment: I still get the same output

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might start here:

```
inFile>>a;
C[i]=a;
```

Where you push some characters '*' into an int variable/array.

What do you expect to come out at this point? number od stars or number-reprensentation (eg ASCII) of start-char

After that you print the stars comparing to the NUMBER stored into this variable/array

```
for(int j=0;j<starsArray[i];j++)
{
    cout<<"*";
}
```

As you say: "The rest of the program displays stars instead of the output." might mean that you output a number of (int)"**" stars

So what I think you mean to do is:

```
std::string t;
inFile>>t;
C[i]=t.length();
```

see [std::string reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `starsArray[i]` to `starsArray[j]` .

Found the bug on this line of code: `for(int j=0;j<starsArray[i];j++)`

EDIT: Heres the full code:

```
#include <iostream> // access to cin, cout
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int buildArrays(int A[],int B[],int C[])

{

    int a,i=0;                //  (I think this is where the looping problem begins)

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open( "candycrush.txt" );

    if ( inFile.fail() )
       {
           cout << "The candycrush.txt input file did not open\n\n";
           exit(-1);
       }

    inFile >> a;

    while(inFile)

    {                                  

        A[i]=a;  cout<<a<<" \n";



        inFile>>a;

        B[i]=a;  cout<<a<<" \n";




        inFile>>a;

        C[i]=a;  cout<<a<<" \n";




        inFile>>a;  cout<<a<<" \n";


        i++;

    }
    inFile.close();
    cout<<" \n\n\n\n\n\n";
return i;

}

void printArrays( string reportTitle, int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels )

{

    //cout<<reportTitle<<endl;

    cout<<"CAMDYCRUSH SAGA SCORES SORTER ----------------------------\N";

    cout<<"Levels\tScores\tStars"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++)

    {

        cout<<levelsArray[i]<<"\t"<<scoresArray[i]<<"\t";

        for(int j=0;j<starsArray[j];j++)

        {

            cout<<"*";

        }

        cout<<endl;

    }

}


void sortArrays( int levelsArray[], int scoresArray[], int starsArray[], int numberOfLevels )

{

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfLevels;i++)

    {

        for(int j=0;j<numberOfLevels;j++)

        {

            if(levelsArray[i]<levelsArray[j])

            {

                int temp1=levelsArray[i];

                int temp2=scoresArray[i];

                int temp3=starsArray[i];


                levelsArray[i]=levelsArray[j];

                scoresArray[i]=scoresArray[j];

                starsArray[i]=starsArray[j];


                levelsArray[j]=temp1;

                scoresArray[j]=temp2;

                starsArray[j]=temp3;

            }

        }

    }

}



int main()

{

    const int MAX=400;

    int levelsArray[MAX];

    int scoresArray[MAX];

    int starsArray[MAX];


    int numberOfLevels=buildArrays(levelsArray,scoresArray,starsArray);


    printArrays( "Candy Crush UNSORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );

    sortArrays( levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels);

    printArrays( "Candy Crush SORTED Report", levelsArray, scoresArray, starsArray, numberOfLevels );


    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you this works but now it only displays ONE line of code instead of the multiple outputs.